# How to add `\macro{}` around the first occurrence of each match from a list with Regex

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk

I have a list of words, list.txt, like this:

```
fish
squirrel
bird
tree
mountain
```

I also have a file, text.txt, with passages like this:

```
The fish ate the birds.
The squirrel lived in the tree on the mountain.
The fish did not like eating squirrels as they lived too high in the trees.
```

I need to mark the first occurrences of all of the words from `list.txt` in the `text.txt` file, with a TeX code, like, `\macro{}`, e.g., the output would look like this:

```
The \macro{fish} ate the \macro{bird}s.
The \macro{squirrel} lived in the \macro{tree}house on the \macro{mountain}.
The fish did not like eating squirrels as they lived too high in the trees.
```

How can I add `\macro{}` to the first occurrence of each of the words that appears in the list in BASH?

Comment: Have you used `sed`? Are you familiar with regular expressions?

Comment: There is a typo in your question: `tree` --> `\macro{tree}house` .

Comment: You included `"bird"` as a match for part of `"bird"s`. What would you want to do if `the` was in `list.txt` and `theory` was in text.txt. What if "a" was in `list.txt` - match the `a` in the first word that contains an `a`? Would `there's` partially match `there`? You need to provide some more complicated sample input and a rationale for the output in those cases.

Comment: The spaces are not important and the software does not need to know the difference between a word. `theory` would be marked as `\the{the}ory` if that appeared first in the document and if `the` was a word from the list.

Answer (score 2):

Code for GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
$ sed -nr 's#(\w+)#s/\1/\1/;T\1;x;s/\1/\1/;x;t\1;x;s/.*/\& \1/;x;s/\1/\\\\macro\{\1\}/;:\1;$!N#p' list.txt|sed -rf - text.txt
```

```
$ cat list.txt
fish
squirrel
bird
tree
mountain

$ cat text.txt
The fish ate the birds.
The squirrel lived in the tree on the mountain.
The fish did not like eating squirrels as they lived too high in the trees.

$ sed -nr 's#(\w+)#s/\1/\1/;T\1;x;s/\1/\1/;x;t\1;x;s/.*/\& \1/;x;s/\1/\\\\macro\{\1\}/;:\1;$!N#p' list.txt|sed -rf - text.txt
The \macro{fish} ate the \macro{bird}s.
The \macro{squirrel} lived in the \macro{tree} on the \macro{mountain}.
The fish did not like eating squirrels as they lived too high in the trees.
```

Answer (score 1):

Good & interesting problem.

I could come up with following awk for you:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$1;next} 
   {for (v in a) if (a[v] != "") {r=sub(v, "\\macro{" v "}"); if (r) a[v]=""}
   }'1 list.txt text.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This will preserve white space (unlike any solution that assigns to fields) and won't incorrectly match the first 2 letters of "there" when looking for "the" (unlike any solution that doesn't enclose "word" in word delimiters "<...>" or equivalent)

```
$ gawk 'NR==FNR{list[$0];next}
    {
        for (word in list)
            if ( sub("\\<"word"\\>","\\macro{&}") )
                delete list[word]
    }
1' list.txt text.txt
The \macro{fish} ate the birds.
The \macro{squirrel} lived in the \macro{tree} on the \macro{mountain}.
The fish did not like eating squirrels as they lived too high in the trees.
```

The only caveat with this solution is that if "word" contains any RE meta-characters (e.g. *, +) they will be evaluated by the sub(). Since you seem to be using English words that wouldn't happen, but if it can let us know as you need a different solution.

I see you posted that partial matches actually are desirable (e.g. "the" should match the start of "theory") so then you want this:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{list[$0];next}
    {
        for (word in list)
            if ( sub(word,"\\macro{&}") )
                delete list[word]
    }
1' list.txt text.txt
```

as long as no RE metacharacters can appear in your matching words from list.txt, or this otherwise:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{list[$0];next}
    {
        for (word in list)
            start = index($0,word)
            if ( start > 0 ) {
                $0 = substr($0,1,start-1) \
                     "\\macro{" word "}"  \
                     substr($0,start+length(word))
                delete list[word]
            }
    }
1' list.txt text.txt
```

That last is the most robust solution as it does a string comparison rather than an RE comparison so is unaffected by RE metacharacters and also will not affect white space (which I know you said you don't care about right now).

Comment: The problem is, you didn't catch the birds, what the OP wants. I'm lost in this case, it can also occur on the left.

Comment: @captcha - hmm, so the OP DOES want partial matches? Seems unlikely. I'll ask him to clarify with some examples. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still new to Awk, but this seems to work. Just beware of words like "propane" when looking for "prop" (and you can't match the exact word because "props" wouldn't be changed to "\macro{prop}s"). You'd need a better dictionary and possibly a lot more than just Awk to handle cases like that.

```
NR==FNR {
    #Skip empty lines.
    if ($0 ~ /^$/)
        next;
    macros[$0] = "\\macro{"$0"}";
    next;
}
{
    for (name in macros) {
        n = name;
        #Sometimes a word may have a [ in it or other special chars.
        gsub(/[.[\(*+?{|^$]/, "[&]", n);
        if (sub(n, macros[name]))
            delete macros[name];
    }
    print;
}
```